# How to create header files for multiple rasters in R

Tags: raster, r, batch

I have nearly 1000 generic binary images, i.e., headerless, band sequential and binary (16-bit signed integer).  I have been succesfully able to load these with package 'raster' only when I create an associated .hdr file with the same name as the image.

Hence I would like to create an associated .hdr file for each image, with the following information;

```
ENVI
description = {
  AVHRR_GIMMS 8km global NDVI x1000}
samples = 2160
lines   = 4320
bands   = 1
header offset = 0
file type = ENVI Standard
data type = 2
interleave = bsq
sensor type = AVHRR
byte order = 1
```

I am drawing a blank on how to accomplish this.  I don't have any programming skills outside of R.

Any suggestions? Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this (e.g., specifying a single header for all files)?

This question is similar to [this (presently) unanswered question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104500/how-to-create-several-header-files-to-open-avhrr-ndvi3g-gimms-files), except I suspect it may be more straightforward in R than Arcgis.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a relatively simple work-around;

```
#First I create an object containing all the image file names;
mylist<- list.files(path= "C:/myimages/")

#then an object with the content for the header file
x<-"ENVI
description = {
  AVHRR_GIMMS 8km global NDVI x1000}
samples = 2160
lines   = 4320
bands   = 1
header offset = 0
file type = ENVI Standard
data type = 2
interleave = bsq
sensor type = AVHRR
byte order = 1"

#Then I paste the '.hdr' extension to the file names (because I don't know how to do this with write() in the next step)    

mylist.hdr<-paste(mylist,".hdr",sep="")

#and last execute a for loop that creates a file with the header content for each name in the file list
for(i in mylist.hdr) {
  write(x,i)
}
```

I'm certain there is a better way to go about this, but this is functional at least for this one application.  Please share any other ideas.

Comment: Other options could be to do esentially the same thing with GDAL's VRT, or raster's .grd format, or write R functions to matrix(readBin(...)) etc - they all amount to the same thing. Note that your ENVI version doesn't have georeferencing or projection, but presumably it could have, and the other pathways could/should too.